# node.js setup wizard ended prematurely the moment i ran the installer

Tags: node.js, windows, installation

I have downloaded node.js from https://nodejs.org/.

Then I ran the installer, the moment I did that this popped out

[image]

No thing else shows up, the installer is in my downloads folder inside the C drive, there is over 25 GB empty space left so I am sure the issue is not from there (I have emptied my downloads folder from images and videos to make sure)
I have looked many solutions online but my case is a bit different. Many solutions suggested changing the path in the installing process, I can't use this solution as the installation app (or whatever it is called) isn't showing up. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, I kept searching and looking up some other solutions related to windows and TEMP
So I found this [Solution](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/313#issuecomment-295527378)

At first it didn't work for me cause I have been doing it to the `Temp` folder.
I then noticed the `TMP` folder below it and tried the solution on it and it worked!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).